# SHA-1 deprecation impact on personal PKI certificates

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure

I understand that most commercial browsers will stop trusting websites with SHA-1 PKI certificates by Jan 2017 so it is critical for websites to update to SHA-2 by that time. My question is, is it also critical for end-users to update their personal PKI certificates to SHA-2 by Jan 2017 to still be able to authenticate themselves to websites requiring certificate-based authentication? That is, will the browsers also stop supporting sending of SHA-1 certificates to websites during mutual authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers will accept SHA-1 client authentication certificates. However, Web server may reject this certificate if authentication server (domain controller, for example) does not support SHA-1.

I think that most authentication servers will accept SHA-1 client certificates (at least Active Directory will do), because they are not subject of depreciation policy, but I would strongly recommend to upgrade your CAs to sign certificates with SHA-2.

Comment: Could you include some reference to support the answer? It's about future, so not easily verifiable now.

Comment: For example, Microsoft's SHA-1 depreciation policy : http://aka.ms/sha1

Comment: And which part exactly does prove (or even suggest) the client certificates with SHA-1 will be supported? I can see only `TLS Certificates - 2/14/2017 - Windows trusts SHA-2 only` under Schedule.

Comment: Thanks. So for me, as an owner of a website that requires certificate based authentication, it is a MUST that I upgrade my site to _serve_ SHA-2 certificate after 2016. If my web server is configured to _accept_ SHA-1 client certificates, it  is NOT required for my users to upgrade to SHA-2 client certificates even after 2016. So in a mutual authentication, it is possible for the server to serve a SHA-2 cert and accept a SHA-1 cert. Is that correct?

Comment: This section: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32288.windows-enforcement-of-authenticode-code-signing-and-timestamping.aspx#Y

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, creating collisions for SHA1 hashes for certificates is theoretically possible but it still requires ~2^61 SHA compression (according to [this](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwi1_JHs2sDPAhWjKcAKHeARDKEQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarc-stevens.nl%2Fresearch%2Fpapers%2FEC13-S.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEQ8YVUoin7zX8GKPNouBLRbLt28g) paper from 2011). I don't know if there is more recent research on this topic with different results. The complexity of 2^61 means that only the most powerful players like NSA, etc. can produce a certificate that has the same hash as yours. If you are a high value target, then you should issue a new certificate but if you were you probably wouldn't have posted on this site.

Comment: That's not true. Collision attacks are not the same as pre-image attacks, and pre-image attacks are still infeasible against SHA1. (Although you still should be moving towards more secure hashes.)

Comment: Preimage attacks are also infeasible against MD5, but you shouldn't be using it either!